# Script used through ssh connection doesn't execute command. It does if execute directly on the ssh machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I need to execute a script using an ssh connection, the script then should execute a second script through a second ssh connection.

As of now, the scripts are created, copied, and executed correctly. However, in the last shh connection, a command in the script doesn't seem to get the options at all.

This is an example of what I have:

Script1, executed with `ssh -T user@machine1 'script1.sh'` from a local machine:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

*Copy script2.sh in the correct destination on machine2 using scp*

ssh -T user@machine2 'location/script2.sh'
```

Script2, executed by the first script from machine1:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
    
cd path/of/script2
   
*some stuff not relevant*
  
bjobs -V #command with problems
```

When the script is executed manually on machine2 it works without any problem, when the same script is executed through the ssh connection I get `Unknown option: V`.

I tried all I can think of or found on the internet:

```sh
bjobs \-V  # Unknown option: V
bjobs '-V' # Unknown option: V

options=( -V )
bjobs "\${options[@]}" # Unknown option: V

command="bjobs -V"
eval \$command # Unknown option: V
```

I tried with other commands and I get:

```sh
ls -lla # Ignore the -lla option

options=( -lla )
ls "\${options[@]}" # Works correctly

free -g # Works correctly

options=( -g)
free "\${options[@]}" # Works correctly
```

All of these variants work correctly if I manually connect through machine1 and machine2 and execute the script with `./script2`.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on? I'm out of ideas.

EDIT with suggestions from tripleee:

```sh
ssh -T user@machine2 
type bjobs
bjobs is /usr/share/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/bjobs
```

```sh
ssh -T user@machine2 type bjobs
bjobs is /usr/bin/bjobs
```

Comment: Quoting the unknown option does not change what the command receives, at all. *Probably* you have two different copies of `bjobs` and one gets executed when you are logged in (probably because your `PATH` will then be different) and another, probably older version when you have a noninteractive shell. Try `type bjobs` from the interactive shell and from `ssh` and compare. Please [edit] your question to include these debugging details.

Comment: The quoting part was just out of desperation. I edited the question with what you suggested. Seems like there are some differences!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate fix is to add `/usr/share/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin` to your `PATH` at the beginning of your script, or use the full path to the `bjobs` version you want to run.

```sh
PATH=/usr/share/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

or

```sh
:
/usr/share/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/bjobs -V
```